# What is the best way to align bootstrap div horizontally?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried col-centered class, margin:0 auto, but I need to see the width of the containing div to a set pixel width...I don't want that....has to be responsive also.

The pen is here:

http://codepen.io/Satearn/pen/WpzJYy

```
   .center-portfolio
 {
 margin:0 auto;
padding-left:20px;
  width:800px;
}
```

Comment: So you want to center it without specifying a width? Or you just want to center the contents inside of the div?

Comment: If you just want to center the contents, I would do it like this. http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/XMEYNm

Comment: If you want to center the parent div without specifying a width, I would do it like this http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/JWLZEb or maybe you're going for something else?

Answer (score 2):

In this case you could add `text-align: center;` to `.center-portfolio` and add `.center-portfolio > p { display: inline-block;}`. But you would have to add additional margin-top to `.center-portfolio`

[View on Codepen](http://codepen.io/hollow3d/pen/rydKjV)

You can check https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ for more info on centering things in CSS, very cool article.

P.S. You might want to change the `width` to  `max-width`

Answer (score 2):

**APPLY THE CSS**

```css
.glyphicon.glyphicon-print , 
.glyphicon.glyphicon-globe , 
.glyphicon.glyphicon-tag ,
 .glyphicon.glyphicon-plus-sign ,
 .glyphicon.glyphicon-tint   
       {
      font-size: 5vw;
      color:#88BA00;
       }
      .center-portfolio
        {
        margin:0 auto;
        display:block;
        padding-left:20px;
        text-align:center;
        }

        p
        {
          display:inline-block;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="center-portfolio">

<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print portfolio_categories">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag portfolio_categories">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign portfolio_categories">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe portfolio_categories">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tint portfolio_categories">&nbsp;</span>
</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This **HTML5** markup for *Bootstrap* based coding

```css
.glyphicon.glyphicon-print,
.glyphicon.glyphicon-globe,
.glyphicon.glyphicon-tag,
.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus-sign,
.glyphicon.glyphicon-tint {
  font-size: 5vw;
  float: left;
  color: #88BA00;
}

.center-portfolio {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="center-portfolio">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print portfolio_categories">&nbsp;</span>
        </p>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag portfolio_categories">&nbsp;</span>
        </p>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign portfolio_categories">&nbsp;</span>
        </p>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe portfolio_categories">&nbsp;</span>
        </p>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tint portfolio_categories">&nbsp;</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```